# The polygon returned from Flattenjs.BooleanOperations.unify doesn't make any sense

Tags: plotly, computational-geometry, plotly.js, flatten-js

I'm using Flattenjs and Plotly to display polygons. The user can draw polygons anywhere with plotly. If the user draws polygons that are overlapping I want the ability to "merge" those polygons and display just one.

Same this request: https://github.com/alexbol99/flatten-js/issues/61

I've chosen flattenjs for this job. The problem is flattenjs's `unify` function isn't returning what I'm expecting it to.

The user draws the first box with these coords (starting from lower left and moving counter-clockwise):

```
p1.vertices = {
  {x: 8.752134706159648, y: 14.578537362157533}
  {x: 12.860528274146239, y: 14.578537362157533}
  {x: 12.860528274146239, y: 16.769683258276256}
  {x: 8.752134706159648, y: 16.769683258276256}
}
```

[image]

The user draws the second box with these coords:

```
p2.vertices = {
  {x: 3.9394450979467837, y: 13.53201991923516}
  {x: 11.099788173580556, y: 13.53201991923516}
  {x: 11.099788173580556, y: 15.625054805079909}
  {x: 3.9394450979467837, y: 15.625054805079909}
}
```

[image]

I use `p3 = unify(p1, p2)` from Flattenjs and get this beauty:

```
p3.vertices = {
  {x: 3.9394450979467837, y: 13.53201991923516}
  {x: 3.9394450979467837, y: 15.625054805079909}
  {x: 11.099788173580556, y: 13.53201991923516}
  {x: 8.752134706159648, y: 15.625054805079909}
  {x: 11.099788173580556, y: 14.578537362157533}
  {x: 12.860528274146239, y: 14.578537362157533}
  {x: 12.860528274146239, y: 16.769683258276256}
  {x: 8.752134706159648, y: 16.769683258276256}
}
// note that the last point entered then makes a line back to the first point
```

[image]

What I would have wanted to see was something like this:

[image]

Any ideas on why this is happening and how I can get my desired result?

---

Edit: I've also tried the following and get even MORE exciting results:

- unify(p2, p1): same output
- unify(p1.reverse(), p2)

[image]

- unify(p1.reverse(), p2.reverse())

[image]

- unify(p1, p2.reverse())

[image]

Comment: What a nightmare. I'm having the exact same issue. Did you manage to find a solution, or a library that's easier to use?

Comment: @YarekT FWIW, I ended up using a library called polygon-clipping to get merging polygons to work

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I actually ended up persevering a little and managed to get it to work: The issue is that `.vertices` is unordered, and you need to get edges from faces, which are ordered. However, face orientation is still causing me issues... https://github.com/alexbol99/flatten-js/issues/61#issuecomment-1837158631